# Limit y-axis of figure between '12:00 PM' to '12:00 PM' (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am trying to plot an timearray that holds time values of format: '12:00', '23:10','14:24'

```
      timearray= datenum(D,'HH:MM');
```

I am formatting  y-axis by using

```
    datetick('y','HH:MM');
```

when I draw the plot the limit of y-axis is between '12:00 AM' to '12:00 AM' which represents a day.

How can I change the limit of y-axis to make it start from '12:00 PM' and ends '12:00 PM' next day
instead of '12:00 AM' to '12:00 AM'

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to set the axis limits like that with the times formatted as you have them because your vector 'D' doesn't indicate the day. However, if 'D' is in order, then the following code may produce what you're looking for since you can infer the change in day based on the x-axis location:

```
D={'12:00', '23:10','14:24'};
timearray= datenum(D,'HH:MM');
plot(timearray,'bo')
datetick('y','HH:MM');
```